# Could not prove that closure is Send

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio, rust-futures

I want to process a vec of items concurrently. Basically, each item involves doing some I/O, but they are not dependant on one another. I could use `futures::join_all` (or in my case `futures::try_join_all`) to achieve that.

Since I don't care about processing results (except for the error in `try_join_all` case), I don't really want a vec of units (`Vec<()>`) in the end; It's just a useless allocation, where `()` (or `Result<(), Error>`) would be sufficient.

`futures` crate docs mentioned using `FuturesUnordered` directly, if needed, so I gave it a try ([playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=292f6e6c978e4e6add2d3e19a5630f02)):

```rs
use futures::{
    stream::{FuturesUnordered, StreamExt},
    Future,
};

fn main() {
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        let foos = [Foo, Foo, Foo];
        join_all_discard(foos.iter().map(|foo| process_foo(foo))).await;
    });
}

async fn process_foo(foo: &Foo) {
    // do something async with foo
}

async fn join_all_discard<I>(iter: I) -> ()
where
    I: IntoIterator,
    I::Item: Future<Output = ()>,
{
    let mut stream: FuturesUnordered<_> = iter.into_iter().collect();
    while let Some(()) = stream.next().await {}
}
```

The error is

```
error: higher-ranked lifetime error
  --> src/lib.rs:9:5
   |
9  | /     tokio::spawn(async move {
10 | |         let foos = [Foo, Foo, Foo];
11 | |         join_all_discard(foos.iter().map(|foo| process_foo(foo))).await;
12 | |     });
   | |______^
   |
   = note: could not prove `[async block@src/lib.rs:9:18: 12:6]: std::marker::Send`
```

Compiler error manifests itself only with the call to `tokio::spawn` present (which kinda makes sense, since it possibly needs to send the future to a different thread)

Using `join_all_discard(foos.iter().map(process_foo)).await` (without the closure) eliminates the error, as well as using `futures::join_all`, yet my own implementation is flawed. I am lost. I suspect something has to do with the generic bounds on `join_all_discard`.

*P.S. To solve the real problem I wrote `try_join_all_discard`, which exhibits the same error, and looks like this:*

```rs
async fn try_join_all_discard<I, E>(iter: I) -> Result<(), E>
where
    I: IntoIterator,
    I::Item: Future<Output = Result<(), E>>,
{
    let mut stream: FuturesUnordered<_> = iter.into_iter().collect();
    loop {
        match stream.next().await {
            Some(Ok(())) => continue,
            Some(Err(e)) => break Err(e),
            None => break Ok(()),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW `Vec<ZST>` where `ZST` is any zero sized type like for example `()` but others too, of any capacity [does not allocate](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.with_capacity)

Comment: Also FWIW [`FuturesUnordered` _does_ allocate](https://docs.rs/futures-util/0.3.28/src/futures_util/stream/futures_unordered/mod.rs.html#166), and since it uses a linked list it's arguably worse than a `Vec`…

Comment: The issue seems to be manipulating borrowed Foos, not entirely sure why but if you switch to `into_iter` and `process_foo` consuming the `Foo`, the issue is fixed.

Comment: @cafce25 huh, true. Didn't know that. Somehow I thought that for vec of ZSTs `vec[0] as * const () != vec[1] as * const ()`.

Comment: Also I think `FuturesUnordered` is unnecessary, you shoudl be able to use  `stream::iter` and `StreamExt::for_each_concurrent`.

Comment: And depending on the amount of setup code in the real case, you might get away with just returning `iter(foos).for_each_concurrent(None, process_foo)` from the sync block (that's a future, it doesn't need to be future-ized). Already the case with your `join_all_discard`. Though in both cases that assumes all the setup is sync *or* can be executed in the parent task if there's one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the trait bounds as such

```rust
async fn join_all_discard<I, F>(iter: I) -> ()
where
    I: IntoIterator<Item = F>,
    F: Future<Output = ()>
```

Comment: Yeah, It does work, but I'm hella confused as to why

Comment: @Link0 I kinda understand it, but I am not sure so take this with a grain of salt. I guess it is something like `I::Item` implementing a trait isn't the same as it being a certain type `F` that implements the trait. I don't understand it well enough to put it all in words and give a proper explanation.

Comment: Maybe that `I::Item: Future` means items are only of `Future` trait, but `<I, F>` means that `F` is specialized to a concrete type, which also may exhibit properties of `Send`. This concrete specialization may allow rustc to see through the async function, and determine, that in this specific case, it is `Send`. Compiler does "auto Send implementation" for futures of async fns, but only if it could prove that everything that fn deals with is `Send` itself. This looks like a limitation (bug?) in the current implementation. This is niche enough (and has a workaround) for it to not get fixed.

Comment: @Link0 After some thinking and trying stuff, it seems that is not the case. If what you are saying (and what I was thinking) were true, then just adding `I::Item: Future<Output = ()> + Send` should fix the problem, but it doesn't. Collecting the iterator before passing it fixes the problem. Also consuming the iterator `foos.into_iterator().map(|foo| async move { process_foo(&foo).await; })` works fine. But for some reason the generic `F` doesn't require any of that. In any case, I prefer other solutions, mentioned in the comments of the post.

Comment: Yeah, I've discarded current solution long time ago. This mostly became a puzzle, as to figure out what rustc is even doing here. Thanks for your time; appreciate it.